# Is God's creation a single event or a continuous process?

Tags: creation

וְהָאָ֗רֶץ הָיְתָ֥ה תֹ֙הוּ֙ וָבֹ֔הוּ וְחֹ֖שֶׁךְ עַל־פְּנֵ֣י תְה֑וֹם וְר֣וּחַ אֱלֹהִ֔ים מְרַחֶ֖פֶת עַל־פְּנֵ֥י הַמָּֽיִם׃
the earth being unformed and void, with darkness over the surface of the deep and a wind fromb God sweeping over the water—
Genesis chap 1, v 2. SEFARIA texts.
The spirit of God was hovering over the waters when He created heaven and earth -Genesis 1:1 -the verse immediately before the above citation.

The waters were His throne prior to the creation of heaven and earth, just needed a rearrangement into two orderly entities.

Could that hint to the concept that God has always been in company of His beloved creation, that He keeps innovating and expanding ?
Inasmuch as the creation is sustained and renewed every second by His will, is a continuous creation from eternity making the creation from nothing disputable ?

Comment: Why would your hint override the simple meaning of the verses that G-d created the world ex nihilo?

Comment: @N,T. The verse says that God'sspirit was hovering over the waters, this assumes that the waters were pre-existing, and it does not say the waters were created. It is heaven and earth which were created, The waters were only laid out differently -rearranged,

Comment: Many commentators explain that the water is included in the general earth.

Comment: Any chance you can share some statements of these commentators please ?

Comment: See Ramban to the verse, and Radak in name of Rambam. The truth is that in order to truly address your question might take a whole book in and of itself.  Your point does have merit according to some commentators, but there are other verses that show creation ex nihilo, see https://www.sefaria.org/Megillah.21b.10?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=he&p2=Derekh_Chayim.5.1.2&lang2=en

Comment: probably not the right place and the right time, and not enough appetite for this kind of discussion ?

Comment: I don't mind discussing it, but this forum is not the right place. It really needs to be more of a discussion. If you want to do it in person, we could work something out.

Comment: OK. You can contact me at pioni5777@gmail.com.

Comment: Hello N.T., could you please make your comments 2.3 and 4 into an answer and allow me to validate and close the query ?